# Three.js: Drawing points

Tags: javascript, three.js

For a web project, I would like to draw random points with Three.js.

This is my code so far:

```html
<script type="module">

  import * as THREE from 'https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js';

            import { TrackballControls } from 'https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/TrackballControls.js';

            let camera, scene, renderer, controls;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
                camera.position.set( 0, 0, 500 );

                controls = new TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
                controls.minDistance = 200;
                controls.maxDistance = 500;

                scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 ) );

                const light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff );
                light.position.copy( camera.position );
                scene.add( light );

                //






                //


                const randomPoints = [];

                for ( let i = 0; i < 10; i ++ ) {

                    randomPoints.push( new THREE.Vector3( ( i - 4.5 ) * 50, THREE.MathUtils.randFloat( - 50, 50 ), THREE.MathUtils.randFloat( - 50, 50 ) ) );

                }

                const randomSpline = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3( randomPoints );

                //

                const extrudeSettings2 = {
                    steps: 120,
                    bevelEnabled: false,
                    extrudePath: randomSpline
                };


                const pts2 = [], numPts = 5;

                for ( let i = 0; i < numPts * 2; i ++ ) {

                    const l = i % 2 == 1 ? 10 : 10;

                    const a = i / numPts * Math.PI;

                    pts2.push( new THREE.Vector2( Math.cos( a ) * l, Math.sin( a ) * l ) );

                }

                const shape2 = new THREE.Shape( pts2 );

                const geometry2 = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape2, extrudeSettings2 );

                const material2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xff8000, wireframe: false } );

                const mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material2 );

                scene.add( mesh2 );


                //

                const materials = [  material2 ];

                const extrudeSettings3 = {
                    depth: 40,
                    steps: 1,
                    bevelEnabled: true,
                    bevelThickness: 2,
                    bevelSize: 4,
                    bevelSegments: 1
                };

                const geometry3 = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape2, extrudeSettings3 );

                const mesh3 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry3 );

                mesh3.position.set( 150, 100, 0 );


            }

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                controls.update();
                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script>
```

Currently, everything is based on splines. The result should not be based on extrusion, but on random points. I don't really know how to get random points. Is there a special function for it? Or can another function be used for it?

I would be veeeery thankful for help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a good place to start with is using [ConvexGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/geometries/ConvexGeometry). You give it an array of points / Vector3 ( which I see you have created under the variable **randomPoints** ) as a parameter and it will create a shape for you.

I see you used CatmullRomCurve3, this may be a good tool to create the curves between the points as you mentioned. We can combine both of these ideas to create a somewhat curvier model.

```
const divisions = 25; // The amount of divisions between points
const catmullPoints = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3( randomPoints, true, "catmullrom", 0.5 ).getPoints(divisions);
const geometryConvex = new ConvexGeometry( randomPoints );
```

So now you have a geometry with a somewhat randomized shape. The thing about it is that it will look a bit more "geometrical" than the example shapes you provided. So what you can try to do is divide your randomPoints to chunks, i.e multiple sub-arrays, and do a similar approach as above, basically saving the created geometries to a separate array, let's call it **geometries**, and then you can use mergeBufferGeometries to create a single geometry out of these geometries, this will give a more abstract looking shape. The code:

```
  const size = THREE.MathUtils.randInt(2,10); // the number of sub arrays can be another parameter to randomize
  const pointsChunk = chunk([...randomPoints], size); // you can use lodash or other chunk algorithms found online
  
  const geometries = [];
  for ( let i = 0 ; i < pointsChunk.length ; i++) {
     const divisions = 25;
     const catmullPoints = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3( pointsChunk[i], true, "catmullrom", 0.5 ).getPoints( divisions );
     geometries.push(new ConvexGeometry( catmullPoints ));
  }
  
  const mergedGeometry = BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries( geometries );
```

There may be more ways to go about it, but I believe ConvexGeometry is definitely a good place to start.
Here is a fiddle of my attempt : https://jsfiddle.net/9rc503tn/2